# Apple TV HomeKit hub can see devices but cant communicate

Tags: homekit

I have an AppleTV 4th gen that im trying to set up as a HomeKit hub. I have it signed in using two factor authentication and it shows on my Apple ID devices page.

The settings app on appletv says it’s connected to my home and I also see the Apple TV as a hub on my iPhone home.app under the house settings.

Both the iPhone and Apple TV are on the same WiFi network.

I can control my devices with my iPhone but not with the Apple TV.

I know the Apple TV knows about the device database because I have a light named “Xmas Tree”. When I say “turn on the Christmas tree” it spells out “Xmas Tree” on the screen and then says that “The Xmas Tree is not responding”

How can I trouble shoot this?

Comment: Did you update both your devices tvOS 11.2.1 and iOS 11.2.1? These updates today restored some temporarily disabled functionality regarding HomeKit hubs and device sharing.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I had no idea they disabled homekit on the appleTV and I *thought* my software was up to date. I just had poor timing in trying to set it up the first time.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that an update resolved the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jake3231 pointed out, Apple disabled homekit on AppleTV temporarily. I thought mine was up to date (it didn't show any updates available and its set to auto update), but upon checking again tonight an update was available.